# Using Laravel query builder , I need rejected bids from two table order and bids

Tags: laravel

I have two tables in my database, one is `order` and second one is named as `bids`. As the name suggests, I am storing all the jobs in the `order` table and Whenever someone's bids for the particular job, I am storing their bid information in bids table.

whenever client accept job `acceptedBidId` sotres `bidid` which is same as bid id in `order` table.

I am having troubles in fetching `rejected` bids for specific user, where we have a condition that all those bids which are assigned to some other users are

I am not able to write query in Laravel using Laravel query builder.

```
$user = Auth::user();
        $user_id = $user->id;

        $status = $request->input('status');
        $order_direction = $request->has('order_direction') ? $request->input('order_direction') : 'desc';
        $order_by = $request->has('order_by') ? $request->input('order_by') : 'id';
        $per_page = $request->has('limit') ? $request->input('limit') : 15;

        $query = Bid::query();
        $query->whereHas('order', function($q) { $q->orWhereNotNull('acceptedBidId'); })
            ->where('user_id',$user_id);
        if(!empty($status)) {
            $query->where('status',$status);
        }
        if(!empty($order_by) && !empty($order_direction)) {
            $query->orderBy($order_by,$order_direction);
        }
        $bids = $query->paginate($per_page);
        return response()->success($bids);
```

I need all the rejected bids for the particular user.enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVi4J.png)

[image]

Comment: Second table is order which has field `acceptedBidId` .

Comment: Order::whereHas('bids',function($q){ $q->where('status','REJCTED')})->get()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following model relation

```
// Model
class Bid extends Model
{
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Then you should include a condition to check for the rejected one like this:

```
// Query builder
if($isRejected) {
    $query->doesntHave('order');
}
```